# How to correct below calculated date field's formula for SharePoint list calculated field?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a date field called Holiday Date which is populated by user. Based on this date field, I have another calculated date field as Holiday Accrual Date. 
Now let's say if the populated date in Holiday Date field is: 7/18/2018 then the calculated field should skip 7/18 and add 90 days to 7/19/2018 so the value would be 10/17/2018.

In theory, the calculated field "Holiday Accrual Date" would show value as 90 days from the day after the holiday date entered. I am using below formula:
=[Holiday Date]+90.

Unfortunately its not accounting to skip the 7/18 and count 90 days from 7/19. Also Holiday Date is an optional field so if left empty I would like to make sure the calculated field shows null, which currently is not the case. It shows some random value if Holiday Date is left empty.

Please help me with the correct the formula, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this - Holiday Accrual Date = IF(ISBLANK([Holiday Date]),””,[Holiday Date]+91)

I have made it 91 just to skip the first day by default.